# Динамически инициализировать структуру в Go?

Tags: golang

Допустим есть функция которая получает строку как аргумент и в зависимости от значения возвращает экземпляр структуры:

```
func Factory(s string) interface{} {
    if s == 'SomeType' {
        return SomeType{}
    } else if s == 'AnotherType' {
        return AnotherType{}
    }
}
```

Вопрос можно ли сделать данный код более компактным ведь если количество поддерживаемых типов будет расти то функция тоже будет расти, и вообще существует ли лучшая реализация данного кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Особо более компактным его не сделать, можно отображение со строки на конструктор типа хранить в виде словаря, так итоговый код получается более декларативным, но и многословным из-за довольно тяжелого синтаксиса Go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type SomeType struct{}
type AnotherType struct{}

var registeredTypes = map[string]func() interface{}{
    "SomeType":    func() interface{} { return SomeType{} },
    "AnotherType": func() interface{} { return AnotherType{} },
}

func Factory(name string) interface{} {
    return registeredTypes[name]()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf(
        "%#v\n%#v\n",
        Factory("SomeType"),
        Factory("AnotherType"),
    )
}
```

В качестве дальнейшего улучшения напрашивается сделать вашу фабрику динамически формируемой, и регистрировать новые типы по мере их написания, что-то вроде такого:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Factory map[string]func() interface{}

func (factory *Factory) Register(name string, factoryFunc func() interface{}) {
    (*factory)[name] = factoryFunc
}

func (factory *Factory) CreateInstance(name string) interface{} {
    return (*factory)[name]()
}

var factory = make(Factory)

type SomeType struct{}
type AnotherType struct{}

func main() {
    factory.Register("SomeType", func() interface{} { return SomeType{} })
    factory.Register("AnotherType", func() interface{} { return AnotherType{} })

    fmt.Printf(
        "%#v\n%#v\n",
        factory.CreateInstance("SomeType"),
        factory.CreateInstance("AnotherType"),
    )
}
```

Запуск программы:

```
$ go run test.go
main.SomeType{}
main.AnotherType{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум можно преобразовать в **switch..case** тогда не придется дублировать выражение `else if s == *`.

```
switch s {
case "SomeType":
    return SomeType{}
case "AnotherType"
    return AnotherType{}  
}
```